# Replacing multiple header name using regex

Tags: c#, regex, replace, csvhelper

I'm currently making a project that can read a csv file and can replace the header name by the use of Regex and csvhelper.

I have lots of csv filse and sometimes they have different header names. These are my sample csv files:

example 1:

```
BranchName,Latitude,Longitude
China,89.2422,121.1312
```

example 2:

```
Name,Lat,Long
New Zealand,21.1212,110.3141
```

example 3:

```
B_Name4,Lati12,Longitude21
Australia,34.1231,143.1231
```

How can I change the header names into the correct header names? Like this:

> ```
> Branch_Name,Latitude,Longitude
> China,89.2422,121.1312
> ```

So far my code is this:

```
csv.Reader.Configuration.PrepareHeaderForMatch = header =>
{
var newHeader = Regex.Replace(header, "@([\w]\*name[\w]*)", "Branch_Name", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
newHeader = Regex.Replace(header, "@([\w]\*lat[\w]*)", "Latitude", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
newHeader = Regex.Replace(header, "@([\w]\*long[\w]*)", "Longitude", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

return newHeader;
}
```

In this code the regex is only replacing the first match.
I know that it is possible by using mapping but it requires to manually putting the possible header names. What I want is to dynamically replace the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really 'into' C#, but it looks to me that you need to:

- remove the backslash left of the asteriks in the regexes
- replace `header` with `newHeader` in the second and third Replace actions.

Also, the square brackets around `\w` are not necessary since you are not testing for 'any of the following characters'

Your code could then be like:

```
csv.Reader.Configuration.PrepareHeaderForMatch = header =>
{
    var newHeader = Regex.Replace(header, @"(\w*Name\w*)", "Branch_Name", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    newHeader = Regex.Replace(newHeader, @"(\w*Lat\w*)", "Latitude", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    return Regex.Replace(newHeader, @"(\w*Long\w*)", "Longitude", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}
```